# Output Directory in Visual C++ 2010 IDE

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I’m using the **MS Visual C++ 2010 IDE** on Windows 7 to compile C++ code.
I need to **install the compiled code in a specific directory (C:\Users\username\somefolder)**. What is the **best way to set this output directory?**

I ran Visual C++  as administrator, opened my *.sln project, checked the expert settings and browsed to the path in the Output Directory of the Configuration Properties. Unfortunately, the code did not build in the right directory but under Program Files (probably because Visual C++ starts at an other directory for the specified relative path). Copying the absolute directory does not work.

Could someone point out how I should change this output directory in C:\Users\username\somefolder? 
In the project file I can only find an 'OutputDirectory', not an 'OutputPath', so I did not risk to change this yet as I am a novice Visual C++ user. 
*EDIT: replacing the 'OutputDirectory' did not work or I made another mistake (cf. comments).*

I would not like to move the compiled code every time I rebuild it.
Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: So you know what setting you need to change, just are just afraid it is going to byte your hand off when you touch it?  It doesn't.  You can't stop being a novice if you don't make enough mistakes.

Comment: @Hans Passant: You are right, it didn't byte my hand off... but it didn't work either. After I edited the *.vxcproj by replacing `<OutputDirectory>$(IntDir)</OutputDirectory>` with `<OutputDirectory>C:\Users\username\somefolder</OutputDirectory>` it still installs in `C:\Program Files (x86)\somenewsubdirectory`.

Comment: Problem solved! :-) I use CMake to do the trick by adding an entry `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` with my specific install path.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to leave the compiler to build in its usual relative subdirectory and then to copy the bits you want copied in a post-build step.

This way you will always get a good build, even if the destination directory doesn't exist (or whatever reason). It also means you can still copy the files elsewhere if you change your build system - eg you build on a server that does CI for you.

Also - always specify username as the environment variable path, not a fixed user or no one else will be able to build your project successfully.